# Why does it always say `moving discussion to chat failed`?

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, chat

The comment section always keeps poping this message to `automatically move this discussion to chat?`

But 99 out of 100 times it gives me an error saying `moving discussion to chat failed`.

[image]

Is there a workaround to this? Or am i doing it the wrong way ? Or is it a Bug in StackOverFlow ?

---

**Update as per 1st Comment:**

- I am on Win 10 `64 Bit` Using Chrome `Version 76.0.3809.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)`
- Shot of the Chat Link

[image]

Comment: I doubt if it is related but for the sake of completeness: which browser and OS are you using? You have a chat profile and are not chat banned, right? Were you logged in chat?

Comment: @rene .. Added the version in Question. I am using Wind 10 64Bit and Chrome. Also, I the chat window says **Oops Something Bad Happened** with a cat trying to run a computer. :P ... I don't think I am banned for Chat - Is there a way to Verify ?

Comment: Oh, if your chat profile is borked (sounds like it is) then you need to have that fixed.

Comment: @rene ... And how do I do that ? 

Comment: You post on Meta ... which you did ... right here in this question ....

Comment: Cool... I just checked again. It's still not working. Let's see if it get's resolved quickly. Thanks for the Information @rene :)

Comment: Looks to be a case of a user merge gone wrong about a year ago. AFAIK, only a dev can fix this for you

Comment: @Rob .. yes I did merged my 2 Id's into one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok; I removed your old chat account (there was no activity) - you should now be able to access chat successfully.